# How to search values and replace with another value from external file with windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to use a bat file to handle one of my daily task.
Let me explain:

I have files names like:

```
newfile_MRG.txt
newfile_DRK.txt
...
```

And I have pairs to change. For example, I will change MRG with XYZ in file name or DRK with UWT in file name. I would like to copy the file to another folder and replace there for example it will be:

```
newfile_XYZ.txt
newfile_UWT.txt
```

I have written a batch file:

```
@echo off
set Lang=
mkdir "Child_Locales"
copy *DRK.* "Child_Locales"
cd Child_Locales
ren *DRK.* *UWT.*
cd..
copy *MRG.* "Child_Locales"
cd Child_Locales
ren *MRG.* *XYZ.*
cd..
```

And this is not optimum. Every time a new pair is introduced or changed, I have to update script.

Instead I want to create a TXT file where those pairs are written:

```
MRG=XYZ
DRK=UWT
...
```

I know how to introduce variables, but I couldn't set loop and reading the values to be searched and replaced from external file.
Could you guide me about how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it with a for loop:

```
@echo off
mkdir "Child_locales">nul
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in (somefile.txt) do (
    copy "*%%i.*" "Child_Locales"
    ren "Child_Locales\*_%%i.*" "*_%%j.*"
)
```